# C++ Vectors: Error in push_back member function call

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, vector

I am trying to create the transpose of a matrix - by traversing into 2-D vectors and assigning the values of indices accordingly.

```
[[2, 4, 6], [6, 8, 9]] --> [[2,6], [4, 8], [6, 9]] // transpose matrix representation
```

**Here's my code**

```cpp
vector<vector<int>> transpose(vector<vector<int>>& matrix) {
        vector<vector<int>> result = {};
        for (size_t i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++)
        {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < matrix[0].size(); j++)
            {
                int element = matrix[i][j];
                result[j][i].push_back(element); // error occurs here
            }
        }
        return result;
}
```

While calling the function with proper main body - I am getting the error in calling the `push_back` member function.

**The error message**

```bash
transpose_matrix.cpp:11:30: error: request for member 'push_back' in '(& result.std::vector<std::vector<int> >::operator[](j))->std::vector<int>::operator[](i 
', which is of non-class type '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<int>, int>::value_type' {aka 'int'}
   11 |                 result[j][i].push_back(element);
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~
```

> If you've any alternative suggestion then it'll be also helpful.

Comment: The error is obvious. result[j][i] is an integer not a vector.

Comment: There are two problems. (1) `result[j][i]` is an `int` because `result` is a `vector<vector<int>>`. An `int is not a vector and you cannot push anything to it. (2) `result` is an empty vector, never resized, so `result[j]` is undefined. Alternative suggestion: build **rows* of the transposed matrix, one at a time (declare a variable named `row`).  When a row is ready, push it to `result`. There are many way to achieve the equivalent result, this one may not be the most efficient but it is easy to understand.

Comment: @kiner_shah - after resolving the error of result[j][i] - I tried to replace that with result[j].push_back(element). But still it ended up with exiting the program at runtime/execution.

Comment: Please, first extract a [mcve], just to make sure you actually understand the problem! I guess the solution should be obvious by then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`result[j][i]` is not a `vector`, it's an `int`. Also, you have to at least resize the `vector` to the number of rows in the transposed matrix (equal to number of columns in the input matrix).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::vector<int>> transpose(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& matrix)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> result;
    if (matrix.empty())
        return result;

    result.resize(matrix[0].size());    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < matrix[0].size(); j++)
        {
            int element = matrix[i][j];
            result[j].push_back(element);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v{
        {1,2},
        {2,3},
        {3,4}
    };

    auto res = transpose(v);
    for (auto const& row : res)
    {
        for (auto ele : row)
            std::cout << ele << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up with the similar solution. I just got confused in inserting into the empty vector. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

`result[j][i].push_back(element)` is pointing to a integer value in a `vector<vector<int>>`, and integers has no method "push_back" that is the reason of the error

you can either:

```
result[j][i] = element;
```

to overwrite the element at j,i position (be aware of the size of the vector, so you dont try to write an element out of the boundaries of it)
or just

```
result.push_back(element);
```

to add a new integer in the `vector<vector<int>>`

Answer (score 0):

### Solved the error

The error is caused due to wrong interpretation of the vector & int - `result[j][i] is an integer not a vector`

After solving that - there's another problem left with resizing the empty vector list. To avoid that - I ended up with assigning the vector size at the time of declaring it. And that solved the whole problem. - `vector<vector<int>> res(matrix[0].size(), vector<int>(matrix.size(), 0));`

> Further explanation - If main matrix has `m*n` dimension then its transpose must have `n*m` dimension

**Whole Solution**

```cpp
vector<vector<int>> transpose(vector<vector<int>> &matrix)
{
    // Here assigning the empty matrix caused error while runtime
    vector<vector<int>> res(matrix[0].size(), vector<int>(matrix.size(), 0));

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[0].size(); j++)
        {
            // Assigning the elements to transpose matrix
            res[j][i] = matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    
    return res;
}
```